# What charge distribuition generates this kind of field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I was doing some exercieses in electrostatics, and the following field showed up:

$$\vec E(x,y,z)=\frac{10}{\epsilon_0 r^2}[1-e^{-2r}(1+2r+2r^2)]\hat r$$

And although this isn't part of the problem, I am curious as to what kind of charge distribuiton(s) would generate something like this.

Seperating the different contribuitions, we see that the first term is some sort of point charge/sphere ($\propto \frac{1}{r^2})$, but I'm clueless as to what could generate the rest of the terms.

Has anyone seen something like this before? How can I find what kind of charge distribuition causes this field?

Comment: Hint: Grind through div(E) in polar coordinates.

Comment: The expression is not dimensionally consistent unless $r$ is dimensionless, in which case it does not have dimensions of an E-field.  With proper units it could be $E$-field of an electron cloud in hydrogen.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That could be an answer - answers don't have to be long.

Comment: It is an academic exercise. It does't have to be realistic. And it isn't.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Technically there could be units hiding in those constants

Comment: @AaronStevens I hope not for then 1, $r$ and $r^2$ wouldn’t have the same units.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I mean if it is technically $1+(2\,\mathrm m^{-1})r+(2\,\mathrm m^{-2})r^2$ (or something like that), but the units have been dropped from the expression

Comment: @AaronStevens Right.  The OP should still fix it.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero For sure :)

Comment: The units weren't in the expression, so I figured it was best not to make assumptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking up the advices of people in the comments, I "grinded through $\nabla \vec E$", since, from Gauss' Law in differential for: $\nabla \vec E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$, and calculated the charge distribuition.

After some digging, I found that the charge distribuition of the electric cloud of an hydrogen atom is:
$$\rho=\frac{q}{\pi a^3}e^{-\frac{2r}{a}}$$

where $a$ is Bohr's radius (which was analogous to my result). Using Gauss' Law and integrating over a spherical surface wields:

$$\vec E \cdot 4\pi r^2=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{pi}\int_0^{r} \rho r^2sin\theta d\phi d \theta d r\implies \vec E=\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} (1-e^{-\frac{2r}{a}}(1+2\frac{r}{a} +2\frac{r^2}{a^2})) $$

which is also similiar to the electric field in the problem, so we can say that the present field could come from a distribuition of electrons in  an electron cloud or ionized gas.